The colors are stying same with the from duplicated object
I have a Hand duplicated and I want to change the color of it but when I do it the object that I duplicated it from changes also and it´s pretty annoying help.

This shows one cube with a material on it and a duplicated one beside it. If you look on the Material tab, you'll see that the same material is used by both cubes. (The 2 beside the Material name.)

Click on the 2 to make the material single user and you'll see that the name changes to Material.001 and you'll be able to change the colour without affecting the original cube which still has the originalMaterial name.


To add to John's answer, if your objects are link-duplicated (they share the same mesh) you need to go into the Material panel and click on Object to separate their material:

